# Terrain Generation using SceneKit

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

I am trying to make a terrain map for a 3D game in SceneKit. I have tried a few options starting with using a MapKit as the floor but it didn't workout very well. I am not sure what is the proper way of doing the same. I have seen a few search results that talk about procedural generation but none with SceneKit.

I am reaching out to you guys to point me in the right direction. I need to know how to start a project to render a randomly generated terrain. What kinda components should I have in my Scene to do this ? I am not after fully functional code but some established ideas on how this is done normally. I also would like to know what kinda resources I need to generate a map like that. For 2D I can use TileMaps which has tile images put together randomly but how is it done in SceneKit ?

Comment: Check this tutorial: http://www.rogerboesch.com:2368/scenekit-tutorial-series-from-zero-to-hero/

Comment: Awesome looks like he just started with the tutorial.. will keep a watch on updates. Thanks :)

Comment: I believe this is the updated link https://medium.com/@rogerboesch/scenekit-tutorial-from-zero-to-hero-part-i-c3f56063b54c

Comment: Can't help noticing the normals are going to be wrong in that tutorial. They're all just pointing straight up. That'll maybe look passable for gentle rolling hills, but it's going to completely screw up for pointy mountains.